# getting data from database asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am trying to get data from ms access database using this code but i can not this is my code is this correct

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT [data] FROM tabless WHERE user = '" & user.Text & "'"
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query)  
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection)    
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)    
    connection.Open()
    'on the line below I get an error:  connection property has not been initialized    
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()
        Label1.Text = (reader(0).ToString())
    End While

    reader.Close()

End Using
```

**Database**

```
|data|
  asl
```

trying to get data from database and trying to show it in a label is this possible

Comment: what's the error? what happens when you debug?

Comment: `Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`
connection property has not been initialized

Comment: That information should be part of your question. Please edit it in there, and realize that you need to include that type of information in every question you post. We shouldn't need to ask you for that.

Answer (score 2):

You never associated `cmd` with the connection, and you never use `com` or `adapter`. This is the sort of thing you can figure out by stepping through your code line by line and inspecting the state of it.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT [data] FROM tabless WHERE user = '" & user.Text & "'"

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()
        Label1.Text = (reader(0).ToString())
    End While

    reader.Close()

End Using
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to a SQL Injection Attack. You should not be concatenating strings together to form your queries. You should instead use parameterized queries.